# mercurial changegroup hook - specify most recent node

Tags: mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook

I want to use mercurial hooks to trigger regression builds (in Jenkins) when developers push from their local repos to a central, remote repo.

In path/to/repo/.hg/hgrc

```
[hooks]
changegroup = python:jenkins.py:trigger_build
```

And jenkins.py:

```
def trigger_build(ui, repo, source, hooktype, node, **Kwargs):
    ...
    changeset_to_build = node
    ...
```

But in this case, node refers to the earliest changeset in the changegroup, I want to kick off building and testing against the most recent.  I have a workaround that uses:

```
def trigger_build(ui, repo, source, hooktype, node, **Kwargs):
    ...
    changeset_to_build = repo['default'].hex()
    ...
```

This gets the appropriate changeset, but I'm not sure it's the best way of doing this.  Is there a more standard idiom that I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to me that `repo['default']` is always the head of the default branch. that could be a problem if developers expect builds for other branches or the default branch is not named *default*.

in a hook based on bash and [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets), i'd use the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
changeset_to_build=$(hg log --rev "heads(${HG_NODE}:)" --limit 1 --template "{node}")
```

that would be the first node without child changeset between HG_NODE and tip; so even if the changegroup does not start in the *default* branch, it is the head of the changegroup that jenkins should build.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm afraid I no longer work in the environment that presented this problem, so I can't say for sure if this solution fits, but the logic of it looks right.